# Segmentation fault 11 on Mac, C++ unsigned int declaration

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to brute force a simple symmetric encryption algorithm.
So I do this:

```
    #define MAX_LEN 100
        unsigned int i;
        char *message;
        char* cipher = readFileBytes("secret_msg.bin");
        for (i = 0; i <4294967295; i++){
                if (decrypt(cipher,i,message, 0) == true){
                    cout<<message<<endl;
                    cout<<"hacked!";
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I know that key is some unsigned integer. The problem is that I get Segmentation fault error, as I understood I am exceeding call stack size for allocation. If I comment the `if` statement and change it to `cout<<i;`, I can see that my for loop is running as expected.

Here is my decrypt code:

```
bool decrypt(char *c, unsigned int k,char *m){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_LEN; i+=4){
        m[i] = c[i] ^ (k&0x00ff);
        m[i+1] = c[i+1] ^ (k >> 8);
        m[i+2] = c[i+2] ^ (k >> 16);
        m[i+3] = c[i+3] ^ (k >> 24);
    }
    string result(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        if (result[i] == 'j' && result[i+1] == 'u' && result[i+2] == 's' && result[i+3] == 't') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT:
If I comment out inner code of decrypt it works, I start getting the error when I add first for loop.

EDIT2: 
If I try to cout< I get Segmentation error, of course it is null here. I can cout<

Comment: If `MAX_LEN` is the size of the arrays, you go 1, 2, and 3 elements passed that.

Comment: Is it C or is it C++? Pick one. Then present your [MCVE], a requirement as usual.

Comment: [OT]: use local variable (`i`) instead of adding argument with unique purpose is to be use as local variable

Comment: Integer literals are `int`, and `4294967295` is greater than the largest `int` on your machine.

Comment: [OT]: `sizeof(m)/4` is not what you expect.

Comment: @molbdnilo: it is implementation specific.

Comment: Make your question clearer. 1) Why is C a tag? 2) What is MAX_LEN? 3) Use unsigned int instead of int. or you may experience overflow.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but the probability that a beginner uses a machine with anything but 32-bit ints is smaller than any epsilon greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

`cipher` and `message` seem to be arrays of characters.  I guess that `MAX_LEN` is their size.

If so, you are going out of range in `decrypt()` : you address element `i+3` of `c` and `m`, where `i` can be `MAX_LEN-1`.  So you write 3 elements beyond the array's boundary.  This is a buffer overflow and the most probable causes of your  segfault.

To solve your issue, organize your loop to ensure that `i<message_size-3`, where  `message_size` would be the real size of `cipher`'s content.

**Additional remarks:**

Your last parameter of `decrypt()` is useless, because you reset it to 0 right at the begin of the loop.

You should communicate to `decrypt()` the real size of input : in your buffer, the encrypted message might be followed by garbage and it would be a waste of time to try to decrypt it.

In addition, keep in mind that with arrays, `decrypt()` has no way to know the size of of the buffer:  `sizeof(m)` is the size of the pointer `m`.  So I'd suggest to opt for `std::string` instead.

Note that the message output at the end of `decrypt()` probably wouldn't output much, because of this `sizeof` issue.

By the way, your decryption scheme uses apparently a block cipher, with a block length of 4. So it could make sense to check if `message_size` is a multiple of 4.  Alternatively you could change the code in order to be able to work with incomplete blocks.

Comment: I edited a little bit my post. So I get Segmentation fault at line 1, even if I use small number inside of my for loop

Comment: Shouldn't it be `string result(m);` instead of `c` ? And you still go beyond boundary. Even twice ! (e.g with m[i+...] and with `result[i+...]`

Comment: yes it should be c. BTW even if I comment out result[i+..] part of code, I steel get Segmentation error.

Comment: But did you do:  `for (i=0;i<MAX_LEN-3; i+=4)` ?

Comment: yes. I am getting closer to the problem, so I can not access "m" pointer in my decrypt function.

Comment: can you show how you've allocated message and cipher ?

Comment: ok ! Now everyting is clear:  message is not intialized, so it can point anywhere in memory.  Retry with `char message[MAX_LEN];`.